# Why can't i do any development with Google Home in the UK?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

Does anyone know if this is a general UK issue with attempting to get a Google action up and running (in test mode) using a UK variant of Google Home?

The issue appears to be that if it is a UK device it does not have access to a lot of actions. I have tried both a test action I have created linked to api.ai and also sayspring.

Both give me the same response:

for my test app (which runs fine in the web simulator)

"test app isn’t available on devices set up for British English, sorry about that"

and sayspring

"say spring isn’t available on devices set up for British English, sorry about that"

Seems to me to be a bit pointless buying Google Home for development in the UK if you cannot do any testing?

Is anyone else seeing this issue, or even better resolved it?

thanks.

Comment: Hey Steve, I'm sorry you ran into trouble using Sayspring on Google Home. I run the engineering team there - want to email me or Mark, and we'll let you know as soon as we're live in the UK?

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks  have already emailed Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this link from Mark @sayspring

https://plus.google.com/+WaynePiekarski/posts/3Dozat8LjHh

So the answer is..

if your outside the US forget it for now or at least until "later this summer" - whenever that is.

or

- In Google Assistant app "more settings" menu
- Select the Home device from the 'Devices" list
- Then select Assistant language and change it to English (United
  States)

from a Google support email

Answer (score 1):

Actions on Google doesn't (yet) support en-GB. It was announced at I/O that support would be coming later this summer.

Answer (score 1):

Google has now launched Actions in the UK: https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/actions-for-british-english.html

Sayspring also supports both Amazon Alexa and Google Assistant in British English.

Answer (score 0):

Now en-GB supports in Actions on Google and you can now change your language to en-GB if you don't want to use en-US. Even you can add both language and this is the best option as it will allow users to interact in both en-GB and en-US. Learn more from this link:-
https://developers.google.com/actions/design/principles#tts-voices